# Navigation bar works on first link, but when other links are clicked items disappear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to list out a side navigation bar.   The navigation should say video, followed by step 1, step 2, and step 3.   It works and displays properly, but strangely, once I go to step 1 from video it instead says step 0, step 1, step 2, and step 3.   When I go to the step 3 - nothing is displayed.  Something is wrong with my code below, and any help would be appreciated.

```
<% @step_list.each_with_index do |step, i| %>

  <% case step.media_type %>
  <% when 'video' %>
        <li class="active">
          <span class="glow"></span>
          <a href="<%= i %>">
              <i class='icon-info-sign icon-2x'></i>
              <span>Video</span>
          </a>
        </li>


  <% when 'excel' %>
        <li class="">
          <span class="glow"></span>
          <a href="<%= i %>">
              <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i>
              <span>Step <%= i %> </span>
          </a>
        </li>

   <% else %>

        <li class="dark-nav ">
          <span class="glow"></span>
         <a href="<%= i %>">
              <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i>
              <span>Step <%= i %></span>
          </a>
        </li>

  <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Here is my steps controller

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController   

def show
    @level = Level.find(params[:id])
    @step = Step.find(params[:id])
    @step_list = @level.steps
end

end
```

Comment: Add the following statements to the bottom of your show action, so you can see how the values are changing when the page is refreshed in your terminal: `puts params` and `puts @step_list`.  Ruby arrays are zero indexed, so step 0, step 1, and step 2 make sense - not sure where step 3 is coming from.  It is also strange that `@level` and `@step` are based on `params[:id]`.  I wouldn't expect both of them to be based on the same id.  If you report back on this comment, I can help you some more.

Comment: Okay, I am newer to rails.  You are probably right in that the params[:id] is the issue and that @ level should be not found that way in the steps controller.   I put " puts params and puts @step list", I refreshed the page and I put together a gist of the response you may need, but if not please let me know what I should be looking for : https://gist.github.com/sml0820/9bbad732ecd3468a4a05   Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params are `Parameters: {"course_id"=>"1", "level_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}`, so you should update this line of the `show` action to be: `@level = Level.find(params[:level_id])`.

Here is how you can debug this issue.

Controller:

```
def show
    @level = Level.find(params[:id])
    @step = Step.find(params[:id])
    @step_list = @level.steps
    puts "**************************************"
    puts "VALUE OF @step_list in controller"
    puts @step_list
end
```

If you cannot solve your problem after inspecting `@step_list`, paste the `@step_list` value in your question and I will see if I can figure out what is going on :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be step.media_type which is not giving you 'Video' and always falling into the 'else' block.